# Argument of type '{ filepath: string; webviewPath: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Photo'

Tags: ionic-framework, photo-gallery

so im trying to build the photo-gallery sample project for ionic and im stuck on this error.
not sure what i means really.
i tried downgrading npm package. didnt work.
all the other questions kinda just confuse me more lol so here is the full error:

error TS2345: Argument of type '{ filepath: string; webviewPath: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Photo'.
[ng]   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'filepath' does not exist in type 'Photo'.

Comment: are u returning `{ filepath: string; webviewPath: string; }'` from an api and then reading it thro an app or webpage?

Comment: im reading it through git bash. so basically when i do ionic serve it compiles and then opens a broswer tab that shows the app itself . but when the error pops up it says failed to compile

Comment: from what i see ur trying to store the path of an image into an image, maybe store the path seperate and try to get to  image with a different call using the path.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they made a mistake in the tutorial. They give the interface the same name as the Photo import from '@capacitor/camera'. Instead, give the interface the name 'UserPhoto'.

My source is looking at the ionic repository for this project on GitHub: https://github.com/ionic-team/tutorial-photo-gallery-angular

You need to change the following in the `photo.service.ts` file:

```
export interface UserPhoto {
  filepath: string;
  webviewPath: string;
}
```

This is at the bottom of the file, outside of the `PhotoService` class definition.

You also need to define an array of type `UserPhoto`, not `Photo` in your `PhotoService` method. This looks like this:

```
export class PhotoService {
  
  public photos: UserPhoto[] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue from what I can tell (and this worked for me) the issue is the return type of this function:

```js
  const savePicture = async (
    photo: Photo,
    fileName: string
  ): Promise<Photo> => {
    const base64Data = await base64FromPath(photo.webPath!);
    const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: fileName,
      data: base64Data,
      directory: Directory.Data,
    });

    // Use webPath to display the new image instead of base64 since it's
    // already loaded into memory
    return {
      filepath: fileName,
      webviewPath: photo.webPath,
    };
  };
```

It should be `Promise<UserPhoto>`. We know this because the photos array takes UserPhoto type entries.

So change the above function to:

```js
 const savePicture = async (
    photo: Photo,
    fileName: string
  ): Promise<UserPhoto> => {
    const base64Data = await base64FromPath(photo.webPath!);
    const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: fileName,
      data: base64Data,
      directory: Directory.Data,
    });

    // Use webPath to display the new image instead of base64 since it's
    // already loaded into memory
    return {
      filepath: fileName,
      webviewPath: photo.webPath,
    };
  };
```

For reference, I am talking about this tutorial:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/saving-photos

Their git has working code for the most part so please use it as a reference:
https://github.com/ionic-team/tutorial-photo-gallery-react/blob/main/src/hooks/usePhotoGallery.ts

Answer (score 1):

I'm also following the Ionic Tutorial

I found [this article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string#:%7E:text=The%20%22Type%20%27string%20%7C%20undefined,a%20string%20before%20the%20assignment.) useful by adding the optional (might be undefined) operator

```
export interface UserPhoto {
    filepath: string;
    webviewPath?: string;
}
```